# What are the dimensions of the design matrices in an lme4 mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, experiment-design

I am trying to understand the concept of the design matrix (or matrices) in mixed effect models evaluated using the lme4 package from R.

In a standard fixed effect linear model (e.g. glm), there is a single design matrix which must have fewer columns than rows, and none of the columns can be co-linear with any other column. (And thus it is easy to determine a fixed effect design matrix based on an experiment's predictors).

After looking through (though I don't understand any of the math) the "Computational methods for mixed models" PDF written by Douglas Bates, it appears as if the fixed effect design matrix and the random effect design matrix are stacked on top of each other vertically, and then passed through some linear algebra operations to calculate parameter estimates.

However, my understanding of lme4 mixed effect models is that the fixed effect design matrix ("Z") and the random effect design matrix ("X") must both have an identical number of rows, but there is no constraint for matching the number of columns between these two design matrices. But this would mean that these matrices cannot be stacked on top of each other due to mismatched number of columns.

Also, I thought that the number columns they each had is supposed to be different, since the number of fixed effect design matrix columns and the number of random effect design matrix columns depend on the number of levels each has for their respective predictors (and interactions), and are almost certain to be different.

So my questions are:

What are the constraints on the dimensions of both the fixed effect design matrix and the random effect design matrix in lme4?

Are these two design matrices stacked, either vertically or horizontally, during the model fitting process? And if so, how is this done?